# How can I bypass this switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I know this might be a really stupid question, but how would I connect these wires if I wanted to bypass the switch?[image: back of switch]

Comment: The only correct answer is: call an electrician. The fact that you needed to ask the question means that you’re obviously not qualified, and (depending on your state/country) modifying fixed cabling without a license is often illegal.

Comment: @JohnBurger i am definitely gonna do that. Just wanted to know if I could save some money

Comment: What are you trying to do? Stop people turning of the light? Not a good idea, you need to be able to switch stuff off. Consider a switch that needs a key. The ones that use a generic key are cheap.

Answer (score 1):

The black wires are already connected together.   Connect in the red wire to this also, and the switch will be bypassed.

Remember you must put a junction box cover over the hole, you cannot bury it in plaster or otherwise make the cover inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

From the little schematic on the switch, it seems that you have two inputs per side so the 2 black wires should have the same purpose (from your photo i think one of them is grounded and the other "brings" ground to something else, so maybe you have to short them). Given this you can just short the red wire with the black and the switch will be bypassed.
Do this only if you are sure of where are this wires coming from.

Comment: ...and that the power is off!

Comment: Don’t worry @JohnBurger i always cut the fuse

Comment: @McMuffin You mean, breaker?

Comment: Yes i do..‍♂️

Comment: And use a properly sized & rated wire nut - don't rely on tape or twisting to hold it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on nothing but the photo, tie all three wires together with a wire nut.  It looks like 34 is the mains LINE looping through, and the red wire is the switched output going somewhere else.  Be careful - if this really is mains wiring, a mistake will make something go boom.